# Adding variables in Javascript's function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clone an td and inserting it to another table adding a new column.. I achieved it, but I can't assign properly a name.. I need to use 2 variables.

```
console.log("Store Id: "+storeId+"///Product Id:"+newId);

var cloned = $(self).parents('tr').clone();
cloned.find('td').eq(5).after('<td class=""><input type="text" name="product_order_${storeId}_${newId}" id="order_input_cat" value="" class="input-text no-changes" /></td>');  
cloned.appendTo("#products #productOnCatGrid_table tbody");
```

As you can see, the variables are "storeId" and "newId". The problem is that I can't add it into the name field of `<input type....`

Thanks a lot, and sorry my bad english :)

Comment: Well, `'${var}'` is not a syntax supported by Javascript (ES5-). You've used the correct syntax earlier: `'' + var + ''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the single quotes (') to backticks (`) which will cause an interpolation of those two variables.

Specifically:

```
.after(`<td class=""><input type="text" name="product_order_${storeId}_${newId}" id="order_input_cat" value="" class="input-text no-changes" /></td>`);
```

See here if you need more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

For a quick demo run this in the console:

```
var x = 123
console.log(`What's the number? ${x} is the number!`)
```

Note: ES6 and up. Check your browser compat. Ignore users on older browsers. VIVA LA ES2016!

If you want to bend over for the older browsers, change this:

```
...name="product_order_${storeId}_${newId}"...
```

To this:

```
...name="product_order_' + storeId + '_' + newId + '"...
```

*sad face*

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings

```
            cloned.find('td')
                  .eq(5)
                  .after('<td class=""><input type="text" name="product_orden_' 
                       + storeId 
                       + '_' 
                       + newId 
                       + '" id="orden_input_cat" value="" class="input-text no-changes" /></td>');
```